# Is Paul speaking to two different audiences in Galatians 4?

Tags: paul, galatians

Is Paul speaking to two different audiences in Galatians 4:5 and 4:8? Is one group those who were “under the Law” (Jews) and another those who “did not know God” (Gentiles)? If so, is the rest of the chapter addresses specifically to former Gentiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bible book of Galatians is one of the many letters that Paul wrote. As such, he tells us in his opening of this letter to whom he is addressing:

> and all the brothers with me, **to the congregations of Galatia**: ([Galatians 1:2](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001595/10/0))

In the topic of "[Galatians, Letter to the](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001595#h=6)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures*, the subheading "To Whom Addressed" gives us more understanding:

> Racially, “the congregations of Galatia” ([1:2](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001595/10/0)) to whom Paul wrote were a mixture of Jews and non-Jews, the latter being both circumcised proselytes and non-circumcised Gentiles, and no doubt some were of Celtic descent. ([Ac 13:14,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001595/11/0) [43;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001595/11/1) [16:1;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001595/11/2) [Ga 5:2](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001595/11/3)) All together, they were addressed as Galatian Christians because the area in which they lived was called Galatia.

So the audience of this letter was to "Galatians" because of their residence in that country. But the individuals are being addressed by their background; some of which were natural-born Israelites and others proselytes having been converted to the Jewish faith.

So Paul was talking to only one audience ("the congregations of Galatia") but speaking about their individual backgrounds (vs 5 "those under Law" and vs8 those who "did not know God").

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Answer (score 2):

Paul's audience among the Galatians must have included natural born Jews as well as proselytes and Gentiles. He used the first person plural in Gal. 4:4-5:

> God sent forth his Son, born of woman, born under the law, to redeem those who were under the law, so that  *we* [emp. added] might receive adoption as sons.

But this does not mean he was consciously addressing his fellow Jews here. He may have referred to "us Jews" while addressing only non-Jews.

However, the were many Jews living in the area. It is unlikely that among the Galatian Christians there were zero natural-born Jews. See [*Ethnicity and Galatians* by Lei Yang](https://scholars.unh.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1284&context=honors). We cannot say for certain how many natural-born Jews were among the hearers/readers of Paul's letter.

Thus, **we cannot rule out the possibility that Paul addressed fellow Jews among the Galatians when he wrote "that *we* might receive adoption as sons."** It must be admitted, however, that the letter's general audience was comprised of mainly non-Jewish Christians.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is actually found in Gal 4:3 -

> So also, when we were children, we were enslaved under the basic
> principles of the world.

Note that Paul uses the pronoun "we" and the phrase "principles of this world" applying to all people.  Indeed, many commentators have observed this such as Meyer:

> **Galatians 4:3. Ἡμεῖς** embraces Christians generally, the Jewish and Gentile Christians together. In favour of this view we may decisively
> urge,
>
> (1) the sense of **στοιχεῖα τοῦ κόσμου** (see below);
>
> (2) Galatians 4:5, where the first ἵνα applies to the Jewish
> Christians, but the second, reverting to the first person, applies to
> Christians generally, because the address to the readers which follows
> in Galatians 4:6 represents these as a whole, and not merely the
> Jewish Christians among them, as included in the preceding ἵνα τὴν
> υἱοθεσίαν ἀπολάβωμεν; lastly,
>
> (3) that the οὐκέτι and τότε, said of the Galatians in Galatians
> 4:7-8, point back to the state of slavery of the ἡμεῖς in Galatians
> 4:3. Therefore ἡμεῖς is not to be understood as referring either
> merely to the Jewish Christians (Chrysostom and most expositors,
> including Grotius, Estius, Morus, Flatt, Usteri, Schott,
> Baumgarten-Crusius, de Wette, Wieseler); or—as Hofmann in consistency
> with his erroneous reference of Galatians 3:29 to the Gentile readers
> holds—to “the Old Testament church of God, which has now passed over
> into the New Testament church;” or to the Jewish Christians
> pre-eminently (Koppe, Rückert, Matthies, Olshausen); or, lastly, even
> to the Gentile Christians alone (Augustine).

Similarly, the Cambridge commentary says this:

> 3. Even so we] Both Jews and Gentiles, as such, i.e. before conversion to Christ.

Also Ellicott says something similar:

> **(3) We**.—That is, in the first instance, and specially, the Jews; but the Gentiles are also included. The Apostle is speaking from the
> point of view of the Christians: “all who are now Christians, whatever
> their antecedents.” Before the coming of Christ both Jews and Gentiles
> had been subject to law; and what the Apostle says of the law of Moses
> applies more faintly to the law of conscience and of nature.

Similarly, the Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary says this:

> **3. we**—the Jews primarily, and inclusively the Gentiles also. For the "we" in Ga 4:5 plainly refers to both Jew and Gentile believers.
> The Jews in their bondage to the law of Moses, as the representative
> people of the world, include all mankind virtually amenable to God's
> law (Ro 2:14, 15; compare Note, see on [2344]Ga 3:13; [2345]Ga 3:23).
> Even the Gentiles were under "bondage," and in a state of discipline
> suitable to nonage, till Christ came as the Emancipator.

**APPENDIX - Other material**

We could remind ourselves of what Paul says elsewhere such as:

- Rom 2:13-16 - For it is not the hearers of the law who are righteous before God, but it is the doers of the law who will be declared righteous. Indeed, when Gentiles, who do not have the law, do by nature what the law requires, they are a law to themselves, even though they do not have the law. So they show that the work of the law is written on their hearts, their consciences also bearing witness, and their thoughts either accusing or defending them on the day when God will judge men’s secrets through Christ Jesus, as proclaimed by my gospel.